# Saving Stata File Within a Function in R

Tags: r, function, save, stata

I am trying to move files from one folder to another. I have a data frame called "data" with the "from" location, "to" location, and the file name "myfile."

```
library(foreign)


movefile <- function(from, to, myfile){
  readfile <- paste(from, myfile, sep = "/")
  temp <- read.dta(readfile)
  copyto <- paste(to, myfile, sep = "/")
  write.dta(temp, copyto)
}
```

When I call the function with the following line of code:

```
movefile(data$from, data$to, data$myfile)
```

It only copies over the first file. When I try and diagnose the problem by printing various terms within the function (e.g. adding print(copyto) as the final line of the function), it prints for every file listed in data, indicating that the function is being run for every row in data, but it does not actually copy the files beyond the first one. How can I correct this?

Comment: Why not just use file.rename directly to move the file instead of read and write?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you really need to read the files into memory as a `data.frame` using `read.dta`, I would suggest using `file.copy`, which will copy files using the computer file system.

```
 original.files <- do.call('file.path', data[c('from','myfile')])
 new.files <- do.call('file.path', data[c('to','myfile')])

 # overwrite will overwrite, so make sure you mean to do this 
 file.copy(from = original.files, to = new.files, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `write.dta` is not vectorised, and hence neither is your function. You can either use `mapply` as @agstudy noted to vectorise your *call* to `movefile`, or  vectorise `movefile` itself. One function to get to know is `Vectorize`, which is an easy way to vectorise any function.

```
movefile <- Vectorize(movefile)
```

This works in the general case, but may not be the most efficient or transparent method. You can also rewrite `movefile` to be vectorised internally:

```
movefile <- function(from, to, myfile)
{
    readfile <- file.path(from, myfile)
    copyto <- file.path(to, myfile)
    mapply(function(f1, f2) write.dta(read.dta(f1), f2), readfile, copyto)
}
```

Comment: `file.path` not `path.file` (unless you are using another package)

Comment: Whoops, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mapply` for example:

```
mapply(movefile,data$from, data$to, data$myfile)
```

For example, testing this in a simplified version of `movefile`:

```
data <- data.frame(from=1:2,to=2:3,myfile=c('a','b'))
movefile <- function(from, to, myfile){
  readfile <- paste(from, myfile,to, sep = "/")
}
mapply(movefile,data$from, data$to, data$myfile)

[1] "1/a/2" "2/b/3"
```